# SpringBoot Multilingual Configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot

Im implementing Multilingual in SpringBoot application, after following configuration I'm getting property file couldn't be loaded

Folder Name

> src/main/resources/i18n/messages

Property File Name

> messages_us.properties

In Application Main class

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
 SessionLocaleResolver resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
 resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US); 
 return resolver;
}

@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
 ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
 source.setBasenames("i18n/messages");
 source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
 return source;
}
```

In Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/msg")
       public String msg(@RequestHeader("Accept-Language") Locale locale){
          return messageSource.getMessage("msg",null,locale);
       }
```

Header

> Accept-Language:us

I get this warining

> [36mo.s.c.s.ResourceBundleMessageSource     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>   ResourceBundle [i18n/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find
>   bundle for base name i18n/messages, locale us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your directory structure. When you specify the base names as `i18n/messages` the framework will look for files like `i18n/messages_en.properties`. the base name is the directory AND base filename.